# Recording audio using NAudio in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, record, naudio

I saw Mark Heath 's blog on NAudio however it is difficult for beginners like me to understand . I have a WPF page xaml file that consist of a Record , Stop and Save button , How do i write NAudio to the buttons to Record the audio to a wav file and save it ? I been searching online for simple demo codes that i can understand well enough but there aren't any. I've got no idea on how to start . Pls bear with me .

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you search for the terms 'naudio' and 'c#' on youtube.  There is a guy who has done a set of tutorials.  I have watched a few minutes each of some of them.  At first, do exactly as he does, and do them over until you understand what is going on.  Then branch out and do your own stuff.  By the way, he uses Windows Forms in the videos.  Maybe you can switch to WPF after you see how nAudio works with his demos in Forms.

Comment: yeah i saw his tutorials but WPF and Windows Form kinda work differently.

Comment: Buttons are the same in Forms and WPF. Well, not the same, but not completely different as in they both  trigger click events. One other thing that I think is useful is to 'divide and conquer'.  If you build a little skill in Forms with the above mentioned tutorials, you can then concentrate more on the WPF part of your problem.